# Does the APL's OpenURL command support bookmarklets?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, bookmarklet, alexa-presentation-language

I'm want to make an Alexa skill that simplifies the process of using [spacedesk's HTML5 viewer](https://viewer.spacedesk.net) with Silk to turn an Echo Show into a second monitor for Windows PCs. Using the MyPage skill presents two main problems:

1. Screen timeout
2. The hamburger menu on the top left of the screen, which can be intrusive on a smaller screen like the Echo Show 5

I put together a bookmarklet including [DaGammla's keep-silk-open script](https://gitlab.com/DaGammla/keep-silk-open) to fix the problem, and set it as a bookmark in the Silk browser.

However, with this skill, I would like a way for the bookmarklet to be applied to the spacedesk page immediately after loading it. So, is there a way to accomplish this task (i.e. does the OpenURL APL command support bookmarklets?) If there is, that would be excellent.

Answer (score 5):

The OpenURL APL command can be used to open a web page or application on a local device, but cannot be used to apply a bookmarklet script to a web page.

More information on the OpenURL command can be read here: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-presentation-language/apl-open-url-command.html#open_url_source_property.